# Bounding box for multiple objects in an image using Sagemaker ground truth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am creating annotation .json files to be used in AWS Sagemaker [object detection algo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html). The format is as below:

```
{
   "file": "your_image_directory/sample_image1.jpg",
   "image_size": [
      {
         "width": 500,
         "height": 400,
         "depth": 3
      }
   ],
   "annotations": [
      {
         "class_id": 0,
         "left": 111,
         "top": 134,
         "width": 61,
         "height": 128
      },
      {
         "class_id": 0,
         "left": 161,
         "top": 250,
         "width": 79,
         "height": 143
      },
      {
         "class_id": 1,
         "left": 101,
         "top": 185,
         "width": 42,
         "height": 130
      }
   ],
   "categories": [
      {
         "class_id": 0,
         "name": "dog"
      },
      {
         "class_id": 1,
         "name": "cat"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to use Sagemaker ground truth to get the object co-ords(using bounding boxes) as well as the class_id. Can some one please provide some inputs on how I can achieve this for **multiple objects** in an image. I do not see the option to provide multiple labels(for multiple objects) in the bounding box task in ground truth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a member of the Ground Truth service team. We do not support multiple objects as part of the bounding boxes labeling task. We recognize this as a feature request and will look to prioritize for future releases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start is the SM developers guide which links to a working aids for Ground Truth and explains the json format. The dg is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-dg.pdf.

For an example from aws of using sm for multi-object detection with SSD, try this:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/object_detection_pascalvoc_coco/object_detection_image_json_format.ipynb

Comment: Even in the dev guide the steps to label multiple objects in an image isnt there. I am looking for steps to accomplish this in the ground truth console. Any pointers to that would really be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multi-label object detection where Mechanical Turk would be the better option.